# set WebViewClient without using a Webview

Tags: android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

Is there a functionality of .setWebviewClient without using webviews?  Possibly through a view instead.  I am trying to mimic a webview without using the functions. I have to use Chrome Custom Tabs and it seems to not have the same types of built in functions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Custom Tabs do not have the exact same functionality or API as webviews. They're better suited for serving third-party content whilst webviews are better suited for first-party content.

All of this means you can't achieve your goal using CCT.